# Meta badge : informed

Tags: support, bug

My badge progress section tells me that my next badge will be "informed" on the meta site. As I know there aren't any tour pages on meta sites. Am I misinformed about this?

(There is a little pun intended on the question sentence ;) )

Comment: No, no, the proper pun would be "*I haven't been informed* of any...".

Comment: To find the tour, look in help

Comment: The tour link in the "help" menu directs to the main site's tour page but the badge in question belongs to the meta site. I guess the badge calculator doesn't have the distinction between main and meta sites, and this creates a problem especially for main site specific badges.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a post about the same problem on the "New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list" page on Meta Stackexhange.

I guess this one is still being worked on.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253486